# High power low voltage DC/DC converter

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter

I'm looking for a way to convert 3.3 (or 5) V to 2.3 V with about 54 A. Most of the available SMD DC/DC converters have approximately 1 A as maximum current. Just using a resistor would work too, but would result in high energy losses. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: About 150 W is pretty serious work for DC-DC conversion. But this is also the meat and potatoes of PC power supplies where they need to deliver significant power at various voltages to the x86 CPU core. So there is a lot of material on the web for these kinds of supplies. But you will need to dig in, a bit. This is beyond my experience. So I'll leave it for others to address.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a multi-phase buck converter. If 5 V input, have you looked at TI TPS40090? At 3.3 V, have you looked at AD LTC3882-1?

Comment: Haven't heard of buck converters yet, will look into it. The both examples you provided seem to only support PWM mode. I need a constant output however. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Yes. Both are constant voltage output.

Answer (score 3):

> 3.3 (or 5) V to 2.3 V with about 54 A

This is quite similar to what PC motherboard CPU VRM do, so I'd recommend looking into these chips. They're all multiphase buck converters. It will be much easier to use a chip that supports multiphase than trying to hack it by paralleling several chips that don't.

That said I think you should consider a higher input voltage. PCs use 12V which is a good compromise: it's low enough to use low voltage fast low-RdsON MOSFETs in the buck converter, also compatible with high ripple current polymer caps, but 12V is high enough that the input current remains reasonable.

I mean if you use 12V you need a maybe 12V 12A power supply which is reasonable and cheap ; 10-12A input current is not a problem for a PCB or wires. But if you use a 3V3 power supply the input current will be 38-40A, with much higher losses in the wires and PCB, and you will also need a much more expensive 3V3 power supply.

Another solution would be to use a mains powered [2.5V power supply](https://www.meanwell.fr/content/files/pdfs/productPdfs/MW/RSP-320/RSP-320-spec.pdf) with adjustable output voltage. This is much simpler and requires no design at all.